# App Store Connect Operation Error Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon20x20'

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode11.4

I am getting this image issue for every icon. I have tried cleaning the build folder. I have tried checking to see if the icon files are under Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources. I have tried entering the archive folder in terminal and running this command(find Products/ -name Info.plist -print0 | xargs -0n1 plutil -replace BuildMachineOSBuild -string 16A323) which sort of solved the problem temporarily, but I got an email with the list of errors and the build never showed up. I have tried added various code to the info.plist. I have tried deleting all the icons and put them all back, and also tried referencing to a previous app that worked perfectly fine. I have checked that the correct App Icons Source is selected under the general tab, and I have checked that the correct Target Membership is selected for the Icon set. None of this worked. I have been working on this for 3 days now. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I understand this is a duplicate but all the answers in the other post do not work.